# opencv videocapture fail to read frame from rtsp

Tags: opencv

I'm getting and error with read frame from rtsp stream of hikvision camera.
Here is my code to read:

```
public void readImage(){
    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(streamUrl);
    if(capture.isOpened()){
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        while(true){
            if(capture.read(frame)){
                System.out.println("frame read");
            }else{
                System.out.println("failed to read frame");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with above code i can read frame successfully if the resolution of image from stream is low ex (704x576) but if i resolution is hight or i run some parallel task then the capture fail to read frame. After capture has failed in first read loop then i terminate all other task then capture still fail to read unless i recreate another capture (recreate capture object). What should i do now? (this happen on both open cv2.4 and open cv3.2 when i try )

Answer (score 0):

You may want to release memory after use.

Put the code `frame.dispose();` after the end of the `while` loop

Comment: Keon, you are aloud to copy OPs code and use that to formulate your answer and to make sure that your proposed solution is taken correctly by OP (original poster of question/answer). Now it looks at first glance as a comment ;-)